# opencv/python: Draw image over a webcam stream

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, webcam, roi

Hey everyone I'm trying to make a game using my webcam where I need some objects to fall down the screen while Im streaming video with my webcam (that stream being my background).

**The question is: how do I draw the image over this background? 
I know how to capture each frame and that I have to draw the image over the frames, but using what?**

- For this I am **using python and opencv and the cv2 module**.
- Ive already searched and I discovered that you can use regions of
  interest to do that but I am using cv2 and it is said that using the
  numpy arrays that is much simpler.. but I dont understand how to do
  that..

Can anyone give me some tips or examples of how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv/14102014#14102014)'s an example. It shows how to overlay transparent images too. You can use the [built in draw functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) as well. There's a neat little [trick](http://bistr-o-mathik.org/2012/06/13/simple-transparency-in-opencv/) to draw transparent shapes too.

Comment: the first example worked but the second one that takes out the alpha channel didnt. Its giving me 'IndexError: invalid index' (Ive made copy paste of the code to make sure Im not making any mistake)

Comment: @Cap.Alvez Did you figure out how to fix the second example