# opencv blend (overlay) two image with different channels

Tags: opencv

I want to overlay two images (maybe different format (channels) with opencv. Originally I use addWeighted, however, it fails on two images with different channels. Is there any way in opencv that can handle this case? Thanks

Comment: for each y coordinate: for each x coordinate: blend manually the way you like to;

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, two images may have different number of channels, then how to manually blend for different channel mumber?

Comment: depends on how you want to blend... There is no "right" or "wrong", it really depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: thanks again for the reply. I want a simple blend result = background * alpha + inputimage * (1-alpha). Since I don't know the number of background and inputimage channels until I load them, but I hope my function can automatically handle those situations. My original idea is to convert both to 4 channels, but cvColor requires you know specific input and output before it can do the job. Do you have some suggestion for this?

Comment: you can ask the number of channels. If it is 1, it is grayscale, 3 is BGR and 4 is BGRA after loading with opencv's imread so use GRAY2BGRA or BGR2BGRA flags in cvtColor

Comment: The question is quite terrible but I needed to dump some code that could be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @YurongJiang If there is an answer that helped you, up vote it! If there's  an answer that solved your problem, click on the checkbox near it to select it as the official answer. By doing these things you are helping future visitors like yourself.

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2018/02/fast-pixel-processing-with-opencv-and.html refer this link/blog

Comment: @YurongJiang It's been more than a year since you asked this question and it has received great answers. Could you up-vote the best ones that help you or click on the checkbox near the answer that helped you solve the problem? By doing these little things you are helping future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, there is no API in OpenCV that offers this feature natively. On the other hand, there's nothing stopping you from writing your own code to do that.

A few weeks ago a made some changes to a function I saw somewhere else on the Internet to be able to:

- Pass two input images: the **background as BGR** and the **foreground as BGRA**;
- Blend them together according to a simple transparency rule;

*(I don't remember where most of this code came from, sorry... but thank you whoever you are!)*

```
void overlayImage(const cv::Mat &background, const cv::Mat &foreground, cv::Mat &output, cv::Point2i location, double opacity = 1.0)
{
    background.copyTo(output);

    // start at the row indicated by location, or at row 0 if location.y is negative.
    for (int y = std::max(location.y , 0); y < background.rows; ++y) {
        int fY = y - location.y; // because of the translation

        // we are done of we have processed all rows of the foreground image.
        if (fY >= foreground.rows)
            break;

        // start at the column indicated by location, or at column 0 if location.x is negative.
        for (int x = std::max(location.x, 0); x < background.cols; ++x) {
            int fX = x - location.x; // because of the translation.

            // we are done with this row if the column is outside of the foreground image.
            if (fX >= foreground.cols)
                break;

            // determine the opacity of the foregrond pixel, using its fourth (alpha) channel.
            double opacity_level = ((double)foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + 3]) / 255.;
            if (opacity >= 0.0 && opacity < 1.0)
                opacity_level *= opacity;

            // and now combine the background and foreground pixel, using the opacity, but only if opacity > 0.
            for (int c = 0; opacity_level > 0 && c < output.channels(); ++c) {
                unsigned char foregroundPx = foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + c];
                unsigned char backgroundPx = background.data[y * background.step + x * background.channels() + c];
                output.data[y*output.step + output.channels()*x + c] = backgroundPx * (1.-opacity_level) + foregroundPx * opacity_level;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below you will find the input images used for testing: the *left* is the *background* and the image on the *right* is the *foreground*.

[image] 
[image]

To copy the foreground completely over the background, just do:

```
cv::Mat background = cv::imread("road.png");         // 3-chan BGR
cv::Mat foreground= cv::imread("tulip.png", -1);     // 4-chan BGRA
cv::Point location(0, 0);  

cv::Mat output;
overlayImage(input_bkg, input_target, output, location, 1.0);
cv::imwrite("output_alpha1.0.png", output);
```

and to perform a copy with 50% transparency:

```
overlayImage(input_bkg, input_target, output, location, 0.5);
cv::imwrite("output_alpha0.5.png", output);
```

Here are the results:

[image] 
[image]

This implementation is not bulletproof for production purposes, so use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone that tried to answer my question. In the end, I took the path that enumerates the conditions of background image and convert it to same channel number and then used weighted sum. Not sure whether this one is correct way to handle it, but it seems work for me, except the transparent background PNG. Any suggestions?

```
private boolean convertToSameChannels() {
  if (_overlayImage.channels() != _image.channels()) {
    if (_image.channels() == 1) {
      if (_overlayImage.channels() == 3) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(_overlayImage, _overlayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
      } else if (_overlayImage.channels() == 4) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(_overlayImage, _overlayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
      }
    } else if (_image.channels() == 3) {
      if (_overlayImage.channels() == 1) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(_overlayImage, _overlayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
      } else if (_overlayImage.channels() == 4) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(_overlayImage, _overlayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
      }
    } else if (_image.channels() == 4) {
      if (_overlayImage.channels() == 3) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(_overlayImage, _overlayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
      } else if (_overlayImage.channels() == 1) {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(_overlayImage, _overlayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA);
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("overlay image not suppoerted error");
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```