# How to remove jagged edges when overlaying a Alpha channeled image into a background image - though the mask has antialiased-like edge

Tags: python, opencv

[image: THis is the image to be overlaid][image: Background image Image to be overlaidused in the code]I am running a opencv 4.7.0 on a windows machine..
Hi I have the following:

1. a background image.
2. another image with transparency - of the same dimensions as the original image. Intent is to overlay the second image onto the 1st.
   When I overlay the image onto the 1st using Pillow/PIL, I use the following commands to achieve what I want.

```
front = Image.fromarray(newlogo)
background = Image.fromarray(frame)
background.paste(front,(0,0),front.convert('RGBA'))
```

In the above, The overlaid image has smooth edges.
Whereas, when I try to do the same thing with opencv, my output image has jagged edged unlike the overlay using PIL.

[image: Image Mask + Mask Applied BG image]

I have tried the following

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

img  = cv2.imread('background1.jpg')
LogoImage = cv2.imread('overlay3.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
overlay_img = LogoImage[200:(200+1080),100:(100+1920)]

bg_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)  #Adding Alpha Channel to avoid error when copying the Overlay image that has alpha channel


b, g, r, a = cv2.split(overlay_img)
alpha = a / 255
r = (255 * (1 - alpha) + r * alpha).astype(np.uint8)
g = (255 * (1 - alpha) + g * alpha).astype(np.uint8)
b = (255 * (1 - alpha) + b * alpha).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("a is",a)

# Mask out the logo from the logo image.
mask=a
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(overlay_img,overlay_img,mask = mask)

cut_from_bg = img[0:1080, 0:1920]

img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(cut_from_bg, cut_from_bg, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(a))
img1_bga = cv2.cvtColor(img1_bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

print ("img1_bgm:",img1_bga.shape, "img2_fg :", img2_fg.shape)

bg_img[0:1080, 0:1920] = cv2.add(img1_bga, img2_fg)
cv2.imshow(" img1_bg ", img1_bg)
cv2.imshow(" bg_img ", bg_img)

#PIL implementation
front = Image.fromarray(overlay_img)
background = Image.fromarray(img)
background.paste(front,(0,0),front.convert('RGBA'))
dst = np.array(background)
cv2.imshow(" dst via PIL ", dst)


cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have also tried the solution given in this link below (in addition to a couple other links) which involves calculation of opacity and direct matrix operations. But, thats too slow and was wondering if anything could be done within opencv-python/numpy processing.

[opencv blend (overlay) two image with different channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103051/opencv-blend-overlay-two-image-with-different-channels/49180468#49180468)

Comment: plz share original images

Comment: oh, the `bitwise_and` is especially problematic. that will not multiply, that will act boolean

Comment: @kenash0625, I have uploaded the 2 images that can be used with the code above to see the results. Pls let me know if you are facing any trouble with that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, having the mask as boolean should be fine I thought as the pixels in the mask should have been enabled for antialiased lines and hence must still copy those cells back to the background image. Is it not?
Thanks ChristophRackwitz and kenash0625 for your responses.