# python: have GPS coordinates and corrsponding values, generate a 2D heat map

Tags: python, gps, heatmap

I have a list of 7130 values which are from 0 to 1, these values represent a "heat value" on a city map at corresponding GPS coordinates and I can extract the coordinates from a data file. Now I want to use python to generate a heat map like the picture shown here. Does anyone know how to do that? Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: To plot over a map you should checkout `basemap` toolkit in `matplotlib`. Specifically something like [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/bagrow.com/dsv/heatmap_basemap.ipynb) doesn't seem that hard to do. To get the smooth map like you have, you could also check out `scipy`, specifically [`interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) to smooth out your data.

Comment: Have you managed to do this? If so, would you care to share your code?

Comment: @AlexisEggermont hi, yes I managed to do this at end, but not with python. I used google table actually......then it is not a issue about code, it is just about handling data

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of details that would go into answering this question.

The first would be, what have you got so far?

Do you have a map image?

Have you plotted the gps coordinates to coincide with the pixel positions in your image?

Do you have a Look Up Table to correspond with your different "temp" values?

Are you looking to create a static output image, or do you want it to update dynamically? (This may determine the method you use to generate the heat-map overlay.)

Once you have those details ironed out it should be fairly simple to generate a heat map like the one above using any of the various imaging libraries available in Python (PIL/OpenCV).

This is a rough (overly simplified) outline of how I would generate the heat map from the initial data using OpenCV:
I would start with two images, the map image, and a zero valued (black) image of the same size. You can then add the appropriate values to all three color channels of your blank image at the gps/pixel locations which will give you a 3 channeled gray image. (So if the value is 0.25, you set RG and B to 0.25)
[image: Initial Map image]
[image: Initial 3 channel gray value map]

Then, apply a gaussian blur with a large kernel size; appropriate to the amount of blending you want between points and the size of your image. 
[image: Blurred value map]
You will likely need to multiply your blurred image by some factor (depending on kernel size) after blurring to brighten the colors.
[image: Multiplied Blurred value map]

Next apply your Look Up Table to your Blurred mapped values:
[image: Value map with LUT]

Then you could merge the two images into one output image using any number of combinations (add, multiply, addWeighted(), etc). Or if you want to involve an alpha channel for a cleaner overlay you could use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv).
[image: Final Heat map]

Comment: In case of console based heat map generation in static can we have a map as base for the heat map ?? Could you pls share some details in that context

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great library [HEATMAP](http://jjguy.com/heatmap/).

Code snippet:

```
import heatmap
import random

pts = []
for x in range(400):
    pts.append((random.random(), random.random() ))

print "Processing %d points..." % len(pts)

hm = heatmap.Heatmap()
img = hm.heatmap(pts)
img.save("classic.png")
```

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO3lv.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you use PYTHON language there is a very short way to do it. You need to install just one library which is `gmaps`. You need a Google Map Key to use this library.

Link of the library: https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#weighted-heatmaps

Here is an example:

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html
import pandas as pd
columns = ["latitude","longitude","magnitude"]
a = []

for i in your_arr:
    a.append([your_arr[0], your_arr[1], your_arr[2]])
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=columns)
gmaps.configure(api_key="YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY_HERE")

fig = gmaps.figure()
heatmap_layer = gmaps.heatmap_layer(
    df[['latitude', 'longitude']], weights=df['magnitude'],max_intensity=210,point_radius=30
)
fig.add_layer(heatmap_layer)

embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=[fig])
```

Here how it looks like:
[image]

After that you can open `export.html` in your browser and can see your heatmap easily :)