# Converting PNG PIL Image into OpenCV Image replaces transparency with black background

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

When I try to convert PNG type PIL Image into OpenCV Image, transparent background at PNG turns into black background. How can I keep the transparent background in OpenCV Image object.

Here is the code piece :

```
# PIL Image object which holds a transparent background png image.  
pil_img = Image.open(ioFile).convert('RGBA')
pil_img.show()

# I use numpy to convert the pil_image into a numpy array
numpy_image = np.array(pil_img)

# I convert to a openCV2 image, notice the COLOR_RGB2BGR which means that
# the color is converted from RGBA to BGR format
opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
# 
#(I commented below lines, to show that I tried them but did not work.)
#
# opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
# opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image,  cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
showImage(opencvImage)
```

The last line of code piece shows an image with black background. I probably choose the wrong convert method and, could not find the proper one.

Comment: If you convert it to BGR, then you loose the transparency channel (alpha) and this will be what the BGR channels have, which in your case is 0, 0, 0. Try converting to something that keeps the A channel.

Comment: @api55 - based on what you said, I tried this : opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA) . 
This did not work as well..

Comment: I guess that you display the image with `cv2.imshow` ... that one shows transparent parts as black too :) check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380318/problem-about-background-transparent-png-format-opencv-with-python?rq=1). If you save it it will be transparent. BTW, do you need the image in PIL? maybe you can skip some steps and load it from OpenCV directly.

Comment: @api55, thanks ! You are right about imshow(). When I save the file, it is a transparent. Actually I do not need PIL image, but when I try to read PNG file from the URL with OpenCV transparent background turns into black background. I just checked it out by imwrite() as well :)

Comment: not sure from url, but you can try with `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` when reading it. If it is a .png file maybe it is worth to make sure it ends with .png (if the url does not end with .png try a dummy variable like `?dummy=.png` at the end)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for **save transparency** when converting.

**To convert (with Alpha) from Pillow image to OpenCv image:**

You can manually change the color order.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pillowImage = Image.open('picturePath.png').convert('RGBA')
img = np.array(pillowImage)    # 'img' Color order: RGBA
red = img[:,:,0].copy()        # Copy R from RGBA
img[:,:,0] = img[:,:,2].copy() # Copy B to first order. Color order: BGBA
img[:,:,2] = red               # Copy R to the third order. Color order: BGRA
opencvImage = img              # img is OpenCV variable
```