# Given a overlayed image (A^B) and one original image (A), how to calculate the other original image (B)

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

Assume the following:

- Two images were overlayed over each other and merged into a single image (let's call it: image Y)
- I have one of the original images (let's call it: image A). This image is a half-transparent mask that was overlayed over the other image. But I don't know the mathematical operation. It was not just added but probably multiplied. Or maybe combined as an alpha composite.

How do I obtain the other original image (image B) given the other two images? All images are RGBA images.

I have tried to use PIL's `PIL.ImageChops.difference()` but this does not do the trick. The mathematical operation was not just a simple addition.

I also tried to play around with some code I found. But it certainly does not produce the right results.

```
# split RGBA images into 4 channels
rA, gA, bA, aA = pil_im.split()
rB, gB, bB, aB = mask_img.split()

# divide each channel (image1/image2)
rTmp = ImageMath.eval("int(a/((float(b)+1)/256))", a=rA, b=rB).convert('L')
gTmp = ImageMath.eval("int(a/((float(b)+1)/256))", a=gA, b=gB).convert('L')
bTmp = ImageMath.eval("int(a/((float(b)+1)/256))", a=bA, b=bB).convert('L')
aTmp = ImageMath.eval("int(a/((float(b)+1)/256))", a=aA, b=aB).convert('L')

# merge channels into RGBA image
imgOut = Image.merge("RGBA", (rTmp, gTmp, bTmp, aTmp))
```

- I would like to either reverse a multiplication (by using something like a division) or reverse an alpha compositing. I assume that the problem can be solved. It must just be something like linear algebra with f(A,B) = Y. I have A and Y, but what is B?
- What is the correct name of my problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you have several linearly combined components, you can restore these components if you have the same number or more of mixtures (mixed with different coefficients).

For instance:

you have:

Mix1=I1*c1+I2*c2 and Mix2=I1*c3+I2*c4, where Mix1 and Mix2 are mixtures you have. I1 and I2 are source images, c1-c4 are mixing coefficients.

Using blind sourse separation you can restore I1 and I2.

For fast start with pyton version check [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html).

I tested it for CPP:

```
#include <cmath>
#define EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC // Define this symbol to enable runtime tests for allocations
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/eigen.hpp"

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
class CFastICA
{
public:
    // --- МЕТОДЫ ----
    CFastICA();
    ~CFastICA();
    // Главный метод, раскладывающий сигнал по компонентам
    void apply(Mat& src,Mat& dst,Mat& W);
private:
    // --- Свойства ---
    // Матрица масштабных коэффициентов
    MatrixXd m_mixing_matrix;
    // Верхнее значение предела по кол-ву итераций алгоритма.
    int max_iter;
    // Малое значение, для задания допустимой погрешности алгоритма.
    double tol;

    static MatrixXd CFastICA::sym_decorrelation(MatrixXd m_mixing_matrix);
    static double CFastICA::gx(double x);
    static double CFastICA::g_x(double x);
    // Главный метод, раскладывающий сигнал по компонентам
    MatrixXd apply(MatrixXd& features);
}; 
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
MatrixXd CFastICA::sym_decorrelation(MatrixXd m_mixing_matrix)
{
    MatrixXd K = m_mixing_matrix * m_mixing_matrix.transpose();
    SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> eig;
    eig.compute(K);
    return ((eig.eigenvectors() * eig.eigenvalues().cwiseSqrt().asDiagonal().inverse()) * eig.eigenvectors().transpose()) * m_mixing_matrix;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
double alpha = 1.0; // alpha must be in range [1.0 - 2.0]

double CFastICA::gx(double x)
{
    return tanh(x*alpha);
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
double CFastICA::g_x(double x)
{
    return alpha * (1.0 - gx(x)*gx(x));
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
CFastICA::CFastICA() 
{
    max_iter = 2000;
    tol = 1e-10;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
CFastICA::~CFastICA()
{

}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
void CFastICA::apply(Mat& src,Mat& dst,Mat& W)
{
    MatrixXd X=MatrixXd(src.rows,src.cols);
    // Переведем изображение из openCV в Eigen 
    cv2eigen(src,X);
    apply(X);
    eigen2cv(X,dst);
    eigen2cv(m_mixing_matrix,W);
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
Eigen::MatrixXd CFastICA::apply(MatrixXd& X)
{
    int n = X.rows();
    int p = X.cols();
    int m = n;

    // Whiten
    MatrixXd K;
    MatrixXd WX;

    VectorXd mean = (X.rowwise().sum() / (double)p);
    MatrixXd SPX = X.colwise() - mean;

    Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixXd> svd;
    svd.compute(SPX, Eigen::ComputeThinU);

    MatrixXd u = svd.matrixU();
    MatrixXd d = svd.singularValues();

    // see Hyvarinen (6.33) p.140
    K = u.transpose();
    for (int r = 0; r < K.rows(); r++)
    {
        K.row(r) /= d(r);
    }
    // see Hyvarinen (13.6) p.267 Here WX is white and data
    // in X has been projected onto a subspace by PCA
    WX = K * SPX;
    WX *= sqrt((double)p);

    cv::RNG rng;
    // Initial mixing matrix estimate
    if (m_mixing_matrix.rows() != m || m_mixing_matrix.cols() != m)
    {
        m_mixing_matrix = MatrixXd(m,m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                m_mixing_matrix(i,j) = rng.gaussian(1);
            }
        }
    }

    m_mixing_matrix = sym_decorrelation(m_mixing_matrix);

    int iter = 0;
    double lim = tol+1;
    while (lim > tol && iter < max_iter)
    {
        MatrixXd wtx = m_mixing_matrix * WX;
        MatrixXd gwtx  = wtx.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(&gx));
        MatrixXd g_wtx = wtx.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(&g_x));
        MatrixXd W1 = (gwtx * WX.transpose()) / (double)p - (g_wtx.rowwise().sum()/(double)p).asDiagonal() * m_mixing_matrix;
        W1 = sym_decorrelation(W1);
        lim = ((W1 * m_mixing_matrix.transpose()).diagonal().cwiseAbs().array() - 1.0).abs().maxCoeff();
        m_mixing_matrix = W1;
        iter++;
    }

    // Unmix
    m_mixing_matrix = (m_mixing_matrix*K);
    X = m_mixing_matrix * X;
    // set m_mixing_matrix
    m_mixing_matrix = m_mixing_matrix.inverse();
    return X;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------
void main()
{
    int N_pts=1000;
    /*
    Mat X(2,N_pts,CV_64FC1);

    for(int i=0;i<N_pts;i++)
    {
        X.at<double>(0,i)=1.0*sin((double)i*0.1)+0.4*cos((double)i*0.01);
        X.at<double>(1,i)=0.4*sin((double)i*0.1)+1.0*cos((double)i*0.01);
    }
    */

    Mat I1=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\mandril.jpg",0);
    Mat I2=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\peppers.jpg",0);
    I1.convertTo(I1,CV_64FC1,1.0/255.0);
    I2.convertTo(I2,CV_64FC1,1.0/255.0);
    Mat Mix1=I1*0.2+I2*0.8;
    Mat Mix2=I1*0.3+I2*0.7;
    namedWindow("Mix1");
    namedWindow("Mix2");
    imshow("Mix1",Mix1);
    imshow("Mix2",Mix2);
    cv::waitKey(10);

    N_pts=I1.rows*I1.cols;

    Mat X(2,N_pts,CV_64FC1);
    Mix1=Mix1.reshape(1,1);
    Mix2=Mix2.reshape(1,1);
    Mix1.copyTo(X.row(0));
    Mix2.copyTo(X.row(1));

    CFastICA fica;

    Mat Y,W;
    fica.apply(X,Y,W);
    cout << W << endl;

    double M,m;
    cv::minMaxLoc(Y,&M,&m);

     cout << M << endl;
     cout << m << endl;
     cout << endl;

    // double scale=M-m;
    // Y=Y/scale;

    // cv::Mat img(400,N_pts,CV_8UC3);
    // img=0;
    // cv::line(img,cv::Point(0,200),cv::Point(N_pts,200),Scalar(255,255,255),1);
    // for(int i=0;i<N_pts-1;i++)
    // {
    //  cv::line(img,cv::Point(i,-Y.at<double>(0,i)*50+300),cv::Point(i,-Y.at<double>(0,i+1)*50+300),Scalar(0,255,0),1);
    //  cv::line(img,cv::Point(i,-Y.at<double>(1,i)*50+300),cv::Point(i,-Y.at<double>(1,i+1)*50+300),Scalar(255,0,0),1);    
    // 
    //  cv::line(img,cv::Point(i,-X.at<double>(0,i)*50+100),cv::Point(i,-X.at<double>(0,i+1)*50+100),Scalar(0,255,0),1);
    //  cv::line(img,cv::Point(i,-X.at<double>(1,i)*50+100),cv::Point(i,-X.at<double>(1,i+1)*50+100),Scalar(255,0,0),1);
    // }

    //namedWindow("img");

namedWindow("img1");
namedWindow("img2");
Mat res1(1,N_pts,CV_64FC1);
Mat res2(1,N_pts,CV_64FC1);
Y.row(0).copyTo(res1);
Y.row(1).copyTo(res2);
res1=res1.reshape(1,I1.rows);
res2=res2.reshape(1,I1.rows);
cv::normalize(res1,res1,0,1,cv::NORM_MINMAX);
cv::normalize(1.0-res2,res2,0,1,cv::NORM_MINMAX);
imshow("img1",res1);
imshow("img2",res2);
    cv::waitKey();

}
```

It takes as input 2 mixtures:

[image: 2 mixtures]

And as result we have 2 separated images.

[image]

Comment: very impressive +1, but I think in the given case the OP has just **one** combined image, so this method won't be applicable here I guess.

Comment: One source image can be thinked as a special case of linear combination with mixing coefficients 1 and 0. Not sure method will work, but theorethically it should.

Comment: @Stef is correct. Also, I do have more information than just the merged image. I know one of the originals. It looks like ICA would not make use of this information. It would only take the merged image(s) as input.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the images where merged. If it is a simple alpha blending `Y = alpha * A + (1-alpha) * B`, then you can use Andrey Smorodov's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58235462/3944322) given you have more than one overlayed image (which you probably don't have).
I don't think you can calculate `B` from the above equation as you have one equation with two unknowns (`B` and `alpha`). What you could do is de-blend the two images reversing the above formula and arbitrarily adjusting `alpha` according to visual impression:

```
import cv2 as cv

def on_trackbar(val):
    alpha = max(val / alpha_slider_max, 0.00001)
    beta = ( 1.0 - alpha )
    dst = cv.addWeighted(comb, 1/alpha, src2, -beta/alpha, 0.0)
    cv.imshow(title_window, dst)

# sample images from http://sipi.usc.edu/database/database.php?volume=misc
src1 = cv.imread('mandrill.tiff')
src2 = cv.imread('peppers.png')
# combination with alpha = 0.3
comb = cv.addWeighted(src1, 0.3, src2, 0.7, 0.0)

alpha_slider_max = 100
title_window = 'Linear De-Blend'

cv.namedWindow(title_window)
cv.createTrackbar('Alpha', title_window , 0, alpha_slider_max, on_trackbar)

on_trackbar(0)
```

When you adjust the alpha slider to 30 (alpha = 0.3) you'll see the original mandrill, for 100 the blended input image.

---

But you mentioned transparency: if you have an overlay A with transparent and opaque regions and combine this overlay with a background B so that Y = B for the transparent regions of A and Y = A otherwise (as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image)), then there's no chance reconstructing B for the opaque regions of A as B is *copied* into Y here with no share of A (Y = 1.0 * B + 0.0 * A).

Comment: Thank you very much for this impressive comment. I did not expect this effort.

I tried the solution you suggested but was not able to obtain an image B that did not still contain remains of the other image A. Maybe the operation was not a simple alpha blending. I wish I could derive which operation was used to combine the two images.

Answer (score 1):

If the images are blended linearly, and if we consider an ideal case where we don't lose precision due to the limited range of values a pixel can represent (say 8-bits in a single channel image), then, I think we can formulate the problem as follows (I think this should work, at least in theory, but please point out if there are any flaws):

If

```
A : image1 that is available to us.
B : image2 which we have to estimate.
Y = (1-c)A + c.B : blended image, where c is the blending coefficient, 0 <= c <= 1.
```

`Y` is available to us.

Then

```
Y   = A + c.(B-A)
Y-A = c.(B-A)
```

Now, we know `Y-A` as both `Y` and `A` are known to us. Let `Y-A=C`. Then

```
C = c.(B-A)
```

Let's now consider image pixels at location `(x, y)`

`C(x,y) = c.(B(x,y)-A(x,y))`

Let's consider two image pixels at locations `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`

```
C(x1,y1) = c.(B(x1,y1)-A(x1,y1))  - (1)
C(x2,y2) = c.(B(x2,y2)-A(x2,y2))  - (2)
```

if `C(x2,y2)` is non-zero, we can divide (1) by (2) and cancel out `c`.

`C(x1,y1)/C(x2,y2) = (B(x1,y1)-A(x1,y1))/(B(x2,y2)-A(x2,y2)) - (3)`

Let `C(x1,y1)/C(x2,y2) = d`. We know `d`, its value varies depending on the pixel pair we choose.
Rearranging (3) we get

`d.B(x2,y2) = B(x1,y1)+[d.A(x2,y2) - A(x1,y1)] - (4)`

here, we know `d`, `A(x1,y1)` and `A(x2,y2)`. Therefore we have derived a linear relationship between two pixel values in image `B`.

Let's rewrite (4) by taking `e=1/d`, assuming d is non-zero.

```
B(x2,y2) = e.B(x1,y1) + [A(x2,y2)-e.A(x1,y1)]
B(x2,y2) = e.B(x1,y1) + f - (5)
```

where `f=[A(x2,y2)-e.A(x1,y1)]`.

Here, we know both `e` and `f`, and their values are dependent on the pixel pair we choose.
Using (5) we can establish  a recurrence relationship between pixel values of `B`, like:

```
B(x1, y1) = e1.B(x0, y0) + f1
B(x2, y2) = e2.B(x1, y1) + f2 = e2.(e1.B(x0, y0) + f1) + f2 = e3.B(x0, y0) + f3
:
```

where `e2.e1 = e3` and `e2.f1+f2=f3`.

For example,

```
B(1, 0) = e1.B(0, 0) + f1
B(2, 0) = e2.B(0, 0) + f2
B(3, 0) = e3.B(0, 0) + f3
:
B(i, j) = ei.B(0, 0) + fi
```

Suppose we find all the relations, that is, these `e`s and `f`s for all the other pixels of image `B` in terms of `B(0, 0)`, and set `B(0, 0) = 1`.

Then,

```
B(0, 0) = 1
B(1, 0) = e1 + f1
B(2, 0) = e2 + f2
B(3, 0) = e3 + f3
:
B(i, j) = ei + fi
```

Therefore, we have derived the required image `B` pixels up to an affine transformation.

This is a very interesting problem. I'll try to write some code to try this out when I get some free time.