# How to crop the given Irregularly shaped object along its outline in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, crop, contour

I have been working on a code where an image is given as shown
I have to place this knife onto some other image. The condition is that I have to crop the knife along its outline and not in a rectangular box.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img)


img_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, d = 7, 
                                sigmaSpace = 75, sigmaColor =75)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_blur, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

a = img_gray.max()  
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, a/2+60, a,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap = 'gray')


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
                                    image = thresh, 
                                    mode = cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                                    method = cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

img_copy = img.copy()
final = cv2.drawContours(img_copy, contours, contourIdx = -1, 
                      color = (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2)
plt.imshow(img_copy)
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work well.

**Input**

[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you may take a different approach alltogether: add an alpha channel to your knife image (convert to COLOR_BGR2RGBA instead) and convert all white pixels to transparent. A similar solution might be to create a mask from all non-white pixels and use this mask while stamping the knife onto the other image. (assuming the background pixels are in fact white, and maybe you'd have to take extra care of the white dot in the knife). - Sorry, no answer, just some hints.

Comment: This might be useful - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/07/transparent-overlays-with-opencv/. Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it starting with bounding box using **snake algorithm with balloon force** added.

Snake's algo is defined such that it minimizes 3 energies - Continuity, Curvature and Gradient. The first two (together called internal energy) get minimized when points (on curve) are pulled closer and closer i.e. contract. If they expand then energy increases which is not allowed by snake algorithm.

But this initial algo proposed in 1987 has a few problems. One of the problem is that in flat areas (where gradient is zero) algo fails to converge and does nothing. There are several modifications proposed to solve this problem. The solution of interest here is - Balloon Force proposed by LD Cohen in 1989.

Balloon force guides the contour in non-informative areas of the image, i.e., areas where the gradient of the image is too small to push the contour towards a border. **A negative value will shrink the contour**, while a positive value will expand the contour in these areas. Setting this to zero will disable the balloon force.

Another improvement is - Morphological Snakes which use morphological operators (such as dilation or erosion) over a binary array instead of solving PDEs over a floating point array, which is the standard approach for active contours. This makes Morphological Snakes faster and numerically more stable than their traditional counterpart.

Scikit-image's implementation using the above two improvements is `morphological_geodesic_active_contour`. It has a parameter `balloon`

Using your image

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.segmentation import morphological_geodesic_active_contour, inverse_gaussian_gradient
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('knife.jpg')
im = np.array(im)
im = rgb2gray(im)
im = img_as_float(im)
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Now let us create a function which will help us to store iterations:

```
def store_evolution_in(lst):
    """Returns a callback function to store the evolution of the level sets in
    the given list.
    """

    def _store(x):
        lst.append(np.copy(x))

    return _store
```

This method needs image to be preprocessed to highlight the contours. This can be done using the function `inverse_gaussian_gradient`, although the user might want to define their own version. The quality of the MorphGAC segmentation depends greatly on this preprocessing step.

```
gimage = inverse_gaussian_gradient(im)
```

Below we **define our starting point - a bounding box**.

```
init_ls = np.zeros(im.shape, dtype=np.int8)
init_ls[200:-400, 20:-30] = 1
```

List with intermediate results for plotting the evolution

```
evolution = []
callback = store_evolution_in(evolution)
```

Now required magic line for morphological_geodesic_active_contour with balloon contraction is below:

```
ls = morphological_geodesic_active_contour(gimage, 200, init_ls, 
                                           smoothing=1, balloon=-0.75,
                                            threshold=0.7,
                                           iter_callback=callback)
```

Now let us plot the results:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
ax = axes.flatten()

ax[0].imshow(im, cmap="gray")
ax[0].set_axis_off()
ax[0].contour(ls, [0.5], colors='b')
ax[0].set_title("Morphological GAC segmentation", fontsize=12)

ax[1].imshow(ls, cmap="gray")
ax[1].set_axis_off()
contour = ax[1].contour(evolution[0], [0.5], colors='r')
contour.collections[0].set_label("Starting Contour")
contour = ax[1].contour(evolution[25], [0.5], colors='g')
contour.collections[0].set_label("Iteration 25")
contour = ax[1].contour(evolution[-1], [0.5], colors='b')
contour.collections[0].set_label("Last Iteration")
ax[1].legend(loc="upper right")
title = "Morphological GAC Curve evolution"
ax[1].set_title(title, fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[image]

With more balloon force you can get only the blade of knife as well.

```
ls = morphological_geodesic_active_contour(gimage, 100, init_ls, 
                                           smoothing=1, balloon=-1,
                                            threshold=0.7,
                                           iter_callback=callback)
```

[image]

Play with these parameters - `smoothing, balloon, threshold` to get your perfect curve

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. How to extract the knife (blade and handle ) and past the original pic onto another pic?