# Paste transparent image over another - PIL

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, transparency

I'm trying to get an image with a transparent background to go onto another image but when I'm using paste it or changing the colors of the image or showing a white background how can I get a the image with the transparent background and place it somewhere on the background image without changing the image colors and without a white background

I'm using PIL but if I can do what I want with anything else its ok

Iv'e just tried:
`image = Inv.paste(im=sword, mask=sword, box=SLOT_1)`

Comment: [PIL.Image.alpha_composite](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.alpha_composite)

Comment: Check this great answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59211216/2227070)