# Draw cv::Mat onto another cv::Mat at a certain position? (OpenCV C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, overlay, alpha-transparency

I'm attempting to overlay an image stored in a [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) object onto another `cv::Mat` image at a certain position using OpenCV's C++ library.

Most of the existing solutions are documented using OpenCV's Python library, and I'm encountering some difficulties translating those solutions to C++.

---

As a minimal test, suppose I have a simple test image `test_1.png` of size 100x100:

[image]

which I want to overlay in the middle of a black background of size 300x300 as such:

[image]

Most of the answers, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image/46198932#46198932), make use of the [`addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19) function. Attempting to implement the function as such:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat base = cv::Mat::zeros(300, 300, CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat overlay = cv::imread("test_1.png", 1);
    cv::Mat result;

    cv::addWeighted(base, 1, overlay, 0.1, 0, result);

    cv::imshow("test", result);
    cv::waitKey(1);
    std::system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Results in a C++ memory error at the `addWeighted` call, I'm assuming because `base` and `overlay` aren't the same size.

---

[Another post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70998967/12224591) that asked about the same issue in C++ specificaly provides the following answer:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

void OverlayImage(cv::Mat& base, cv::Mat& overlay, std::pair<int, int> pos)
{
    cv::Size fsize{overlay.size()};
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::Mat maskInv;
    cv::cvtColor(overlay, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::threshold(gray, mask, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::bitwise_not(mask, maskInv);

    cv::Mat roi{base(cv::Range(pos.first, pos.second + fsize.width), cv::Range(pos.second, fsize.height))};
    cv::Mat backBg;
    cv::Mat frontBg;
    cv::bitwise_and(roi, roi, backBg, maskInv);
    cv::bitwise_and(overlay, overlay, frontBg, mask);

    cv::Mat result;
    cv::add(backBg, frontBg, result);
    cv::addWeighted(roi, 0.1, result, 0.9, 0.0, result);
    result.copyTo(base(cv::Rect(pos.first, pos.second, fsize.width, fsize.height)));
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat base = cv::Mat::zeros(300, 300, CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat overlay = cv::imread("test_1.png", 1);
    
    OverlayImage(base, overlay, std::pair<int, int>(0, 0));

    cv::imshow("test", base);
    cv::waitKey(1);
    std::system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

While this solution appears to work with a position of `(0, 0)`:

[image]

It doesn't appear to work for any other position other than `(0, 0)`.

If either of the position components are positive, a C++ memory error occurs at the line:

```
cv::bitwise_and(roi, roi, backBg, maskInv);
```

If either of the position components are negative, an error occurs within the `cv::Mat` constructor, from the line:

```
cv::Mat roi{base(cv::Range(pos.first, pos.second + fsize.width), cv::Range(pos.second, fsize.height))};
```

---

What is the proper way to overlay a `cv::Mat` image onto another `cv::Mat` image at a certain position using OpenCV's C++ library?
(sidenote: the background will not always be black as in my example, and I wish for the image to be partially visible if I place it close to the `base` images' edges)

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: is the background always black?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz nah, thanks for pointing that out I should have specified it in my post.

Comment: your question keeps creeping in scope. you basically want a complete solution for overlay, at arbitrary positions, with clipping, given alpha channel, and additional whole-overlay transparency value... and your question still starts with specifics that you don't care about, like "black background" and "300x300". you ***already found*** the canonical question and lots of answers to deal with this. you even linked to that answer that clearly is defective, while ignoring the answer that *does* do the blending properly. all you've got left to do is the clipping calculations.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz not quite sure what you're talking about when you mention "given alpha channel" and "additional whole-overlay transparency value". The only parameter I provide to the `OverlayImage` function in my example above is `pos` for position, I didn't ask about any opacity or transparency values. And I didn't know whether the other answers in the links I provided were correct because, as I mentioned in my post, I didn't really know how to translate various Python code snippets, such as the range clipping. Since the only C++ answer I found didn't work properly, I asked here myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cv::Mat roi{base(cv::Range(pos.first, pos.second + fsize.width), cv::Range(pos.second, fsize.height))};
```

This line is a mess.
Maybe, should be

```
cv::Mat roi{base(cv::Range(pos.second, pos.second + fsize.height), cv::Range(pos.first, pos.first+fsize.width))};
```

---

If you want to support the situation that `overlay` is not completely included in `base`, like this:

```
inline cv::Range OverlapRange( const cv::Range &A, const cv::Range &B )
{   return cv::Range( std::max( A.start, B.start ), std::min( A.end, B.end ) ); }

inline bool IsEmpty( const cv::Range &R ){  return ( R.end <= R.start );    }

void OverlayImage( cv::Mat& base, cv::Mat& overlay, std::pair<int, int> pos )
{
    auto BaseRowRange = OverlapRange( cv::Range{ 0, base.rows }, { pos.second, pos.second+overlay.rows } );
    auto BaseColRange = OverlapRange( cv::Range{ 0, base.cols }, { pos.first, pos.first+overlay.cols } );
    if( IsEmpty( BaseRowRange ) || IsEmpty( BaseColRange ) )return;

    auto Base_roi = base(BaseRowRange,BaseColRange);
    auto OV_roi = overlay(
        cv::Rect(
            BaseColRange.start - pos.first,
            BaseRowRange.start - pos.second,
            BaseColRange.end - BaseColRange.start,
            BaseRowRange.end - BaseRowRange.start
        )
    );

    cv::Mat BkgndMask;
    cv::inRange( OV_roi, cv::Scalar(0,0,0), cv::Scalar(0,0,0), BkgndMask );

    auto Result = Base_roi.clone();
    OV_roi.copyTo( Result, ~BkgndMask );

    cv::addWeighted( Base_roi, 0.1, Result, 0.9, 0, Base_roi );
}
```

For example, when `main()` is below, the result becomes:

[image]

```
int main()
{
    //base is small green image
    cv::Mat base = cv::Mat(60, 60, CV_8UC3);
    base = cv::Scalar( 0,128,0 );
    //This is the your test image
    cv::Mat overlay = cv::imread("test1.png", 1);

    OverlayImage( base, overlay, std::pair<int, int>(-30, 25) );
    cv::imshow("test", base);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I do indeed want to have the ability to include the image partially if I try to place it near the edges of the base image. I should have also specified that in the original question...

Comment: As an additional question; I'm curious, if I hypothetically wanted to overlay the image with a certain opacity, do I just change the `alpha` argument of the `addWeighted` call?

Comment: For example, you can add `alpha` argument if needed.
To do it, you should check the specification of the function `addWeighted` in OpenCV official reference. Then you'll know how to change opacity.

Answer (score 2):

Your slicing using `cv::Range` is not right - you are slicing a smaller image than the "overlay". In fact, you don't need the slicing at all. You can read the image directly as `BGRA`, use the *alpha* channel to create a binary mask via `thresholding`, then, `AND` the mask with the original `BGR` channels.

Next, use the "base" image as canvas and paste the masked image anywhere inside it. **Be careful to paste it within the canvas dimensions**, otherwise you'll get an exception. Use the [`copyTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77) method from the `cv::Mat` class.

Here's your code modified:

```
void OverlayImage(cv::Mat& base, cv::Mat& overlay, std::pair<int, int> pos)
{
    // Create overlay mask:
    cv::Mat channels[4];
    // Split channels:
    cv::split(overlay, channels);

    // Threshold alpha:
    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::threshold(channels[3], mask, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);

    // Create BGR overlay:
    cv::Mat BGR;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> temp = {channels[0], channels[1], channels[2]};
    cv::merge(temp, BGR);

    // And mask an overlay:
    cv::bitwise_and(BGR, BGR, mask);

    // Get "overlay" dimensions:
    int overlayWidth = BGR.cols;
    int overlayHeight = BGR.rows;

    // Paste "overlay" in canvas at position pos:
    // Hint: small_image.copyTo(big_image(cv::Rect(x,y,small_image.cols, small_image.rows)));
    BGR.copyTo(base(cv::Rect(pos.first, pos.second, overlayWidth, overlayHeight)));
}

int main()
{

    std::string imagePath = "D://opencvImages//ocpaKm.png";
    cv::Mat base = cv::Mat::zeros(300, 300, CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat overlay = cv::imread(imagePath, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    // Paste at center of 300 x 300 image:
    int x = 0.5 * (base.cols - overlay.cols);
    int y = 0.5 * (base.rows - overlay.rows);

    // Get final image:
    OverlayImage(base, overlay, std::pair<int, int>(x, y));

    cv::imshow("Out Image", base);
    cv::waitKey(0);


    return 0;
}
```

This is the result trying to paste the image at the center of the canvas:

[image]

Again, be careful while using `copyTo` because if, somehow, the smaller image gets pasted outside the larger image (even one row/col) you'll raise an exception, so a formal check for these conditions is advised before you attempt to paste the image.

Comment: careful with the dropping of alpha channels. transparent pixels may contain arbitrary values. can't assume that they're black.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You are right. Thanks for the observation. I included a step to explicitly create a binary mask using the alpha channel.

Comment: @stateMachine thanks for providing this answer, it appears to work fine. However I also wish to be able to have the image visible if it clips outside the ranges of `base`, which is something I should have specified in my original question... Your solution appears to work as well though.

Comment: binary masks are poor alpha channels. the alpha channel's purpose is to be used in a multiplication.