# Apply gradient mask in image (with transparency)

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, transition

I would like to apply gradient mask into png image with transparency in python openCv.

So I have an image like here (with transparency png):
[image]

and I generated mask:

[image: mask]

And I would like to have, the object with smooth mask gradient like did in photoshop:
[image: photoshop]

I tried to do it with:

```
def applyGradientToReflection(reflectionPath, gradientMask):
    reflection_img = cv.imread(reflectionPath, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    gradientMask = cv.cvtColor(gradientMask, cv.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
    gradientReflectionMask = cv.bitwise_and(reflection_img, reflection_img, mask=gradientMask)
    return gradientReflectionMask
```

but with `bitwise_and` it's binary without nice, smooth transition.

[image]

Comment: yes, because the code you attempted does not blend. it's purely binary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image