# Convert OpenCV Python Slicing to C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to implement the following python code from here into C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59211216/22836270

```
import cv2

background = cv2.imread("background.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
foreground = cv2.imread("overlay.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# normalize alpha channels from 0-255 to 0-1
alpha_background = background[:,:,3] / 255.0
alpha_foreground = foreground[:,:,3] / 255.0

# set adjusted colors
for color in range(0, 3):
    background[:,:,color] = alpha_foreground * foreground[:,:,color] + \
        alpha_background * background[:,:,color] * (1 - alpha_foreground)

# set adjusted alpha and denormalize back to 0-255
background[:,:,3] = (1 - (1 - alpha_foreground) * (1 - alpha_background)) * 255

# display the image
cv2.imshow("Composited image", background)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Specifically, I'm having trouble understanding the `alpha_background = background[:,:,3] / 255.0`

and `for color in range(0, 3): background[:,:,color] = alpha_foreground * foreground[:,:,color] + \ alpha_background * background[:,:,color] * (1 - alpha_foreground)`

parts and how to implement them in C++.

```
    cv::Mat back = cv::imread(bFile, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    cv::Mat fore = cv::imread(fFile, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    std::vector<float> alpha_background;
    std::vector<float> alpha_foreground;
    //normalize alpha channels from 0-255 to 0-1
    for(int i=0; i<back.size(); i = i+3){
        std::vector<float> alpha_background.pushback(back[i] / 255.0);
        std::vector<float> alpha_foreground.pushback(fore[i] / 255.0);
    }
```

I now realize that the loop is definitely wrong, and it should be a double loop iterating through rows and cols, but I still don't get what the '3' is for.

Comment: Took me a second to realize this has nothing to do with [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/4581301)

Comment: Do you understand what `alpha_background = background[:,:,3] / 255.0` is doing in Python? If not stop now. In order to translate code from one language to another you need to understand both languages fairly well. Well enough to fully understand the behaviour a line of code has in order to understand the line in context with the lines around it and ultimately the whole function. You can't just translate code 1:1 any better than you can translate English to Japanese 1:1. You have to understand the behaviour and reimplement the same behaviour in the new language.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah. I actually think I figured it out. I ended up using a double for loop and a ptr for the row. The '3' was just the alpha channel. In opencv, the channels are in the order BGRA.