# Overlay matplotlib plot with transparent background on to image

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib

I try to overlay a matplot plot on to a specific place of an image with opencv. The problem is that the overlay always has a black or white background, and when I overlay it on a background image, the background image is darker or lighter than the original. I want to do this for every frame of a video, so the solution must be performed.

My first approach was to lay the graph on to a transparent image and overlay this image on to the background.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

# save graph as png with transparent background
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])

canvas.draw()
fig.savefig("Test", transparent=True)

graph = cv2.imread('Test.png')

# give graph png a alpha channel with alpha 0
graph = cv2.cvtColor(graph, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
graph[:, :, 3] = 0

# read background image
background = cv2.imread('hill-966202_960_720.jpg')
background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)

# create transparent background image with size of background image
background_y, background_x, background_channel = background.shape
transparent_image = np.full((background_y, background_x, background_channel), [255, 255, 255, 0])

# put graph on to transparent background
y, x = 80, 123
overlay_y, overlay_x, _ = graph.shape
transparent_image[y:(y + overlay_y), x:(x + overlay_x)] = graph[:, :, :]

transparent_image = transparent_image.astype(np.uint8)
added_image = cv2.addWeighted(transparent_image, 0.4, background, 0.6, 0)

cv2.imshow("TEST", added_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Result of first approach]

When you compare this to the original background image you can see the white background from the overlay.

[image: original background]

My Second approach was to overlay the image on to a copy from the background, and overlay this again over the original background.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

# save graph as png with transparent background
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])

canvas.draw()
fig.savefig("Test", transparent=True)

graph = cv2.imread('Test.png')

# give graph png a alpha channel with alpha 0
graph = cv2.cvtColor(graph, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
graph[:, :, 3] = 0

# read background image
background = cv2.imread('hill-966202_960_720.jpg')
background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
background_copy = background.copy()

# put graph on to background copy
y, x = 80, 123
overlay_y, overlay_x, _ = graph.shape
background_copy[y:(y + overlay_y), x:(x + overlay_x)] = graph[:, :, :]

added_image = cv2.addWeighted(background_copy, 0.4, background, 0.6, 0)

cv2.imshow("TEST", added_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The resulting has still a background around the graph

[image: Result of second approach]

My last approach was to cut the background from the graph out, pixel by pixel.

```
import cv2
import numpy
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import time

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3])

canvas.draw()
buf = canvas.buffer_rgba()

graph_as_array = np.asarray(buf)

background = cv2.imread('hill-966202_960_720.jpg')
background = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
background_copy = background.copy()

y, x = 80, 123

overlay_y, overlay_x, _ = graph_as_array.shape

background_copy[y:(y + overlay_y), x:(x + overlay_x)] = graph_as_array[:, :, :]

for height in range(y, y + overlay_y):
    for width in range(x, x + overlay_x):
        pixel = background_copy[height][width]
        if pixel[0] == 255 and pixel[1] == 255 and pixel[2] == 255:
            background_copy[height][width] = background[height][width]
end = time.time()

cv2.imshow("TEST", background_copy)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result is good, but it takes too long, I want to do this for every frame of a video, so it must be performed.

[image: Result of final approach]

Comment: Please post your overlay image.  Create a mask for the overlay image (by thresholding the overlay) and use that to combine the overlay and background

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using openCV to overlay transparent image onto another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image)

Comment: do not threshold. that's bad. transparency isn't 0 or 255. the alpha channel has scalar values that determine the blending strength per pixel. -- you need to tell matplotlib to set the background to be transparent. then this would work. as long as it's a white background, you'd have to implement a "blend mode" like in photoshop.