How to do composite from PIL using only OpenCV?
Hello I want to combine a green image mask (3 channels with a squared figure only with the green channel as 255) with a 3 channels image using opencv in python. I cannot use PIL.Image.composite since I don't have privileges to install it (not administrator).
OpenCV has a function called addweighted, which does something similar to PIL.Image.composite, however since the mask is binary and this is applied in the whole image, the rest of the image becomes darker for example when the Alpha and Beta values have 0.5 value and Gamma makes the image whiter, but the original colors of the image get lost
To correct this I have to add to an empty array, the original image without the ROI and ROI with the mix of the mask and image (addWeighted) which for one image could be something trivial, but for several images for example 10T this start consuming more time.
I also tried something like this however when I load an image using the IMREAD_UNCHANGED option, the alpha channel does not appear. a colored image is read as a 3 dimensions image and a grayscale/binary image is read as a 2 dimensions image.

Post example images to show the input and the result you want.

What I am looking for is a method or to know if there is a way for opencv to emulate the PIL.Image.composite method, since the one of weighted sum is for the whole image, and I need this weighted sum only on a ROI given by a mask

if "the alpha channel does not appear", the file does not have an alpha channel.

Thanks, that's why I clarified it because my question was marked as a repeated one, related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image but in fact it isn't

so? you said you have a mask, right? so use the mask. a mask is the boolean special case of an alpha channel. -- show us what you tried. not just a link to "something like this", but precisely what you tried. [mre]
