# OpenCV : transparency is not being displayed

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm using OpenCV wherein I'm trying to copy one image with a certain level of transparency on to the top of another one image. But in the end, instead of having the transparent image, I see the whole checkered background. Both images have 4 channels. The image with the flowers was obtained with the **GrabCut** method and then transformed to a BGRA.

I`m copying the image normally using:

```
  flowers.copyTo(newimg(Rect(0,0, flowers.cols, flowers.rows)));
  imwrite("test.png", newimg);
```

Any ideas of why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: You can see how to add a transparent image from [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376337/applying-overlays-to-image-with-varying-transparency/41381887#41381887) I answered a month ago. The code is in python, but you can easily convert to C++.

Comment: copyTo just overwrites everything, it doesn't "apply" transparency.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37087972/5294258)

Comment: Thank you guys!! Both links were helpful!