# Overlay smaller image in a larger image in OpenCV C#

Tags: c#, python, opencv, overlay

I have already searched the answer in python.
But I don't know how to convert it into C#

Python code:  (copy from [[overlay a smaller image on a larger image python OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv/14102014#14102014][1]))

```
import cv2
s_img = cv2.imread("smaller_image.png")
l_img = cv2.imread("larger_image.jpg")
x_offset=y_offset=50
l_img[y_offset:y_offset+s_img.shape[0],x_offset:x_offset+s_img.shape[1]] = s_img
```

//alpha channel

```
s_img = cv2.imread("smaller_image.png", -1)
for c in range(0,3):
l_img[y_offset:y_offset+s_img.shape[0], 
x_offset:x_offset+s_img.shape[1], c] =  s_img[:,:,c] * (s_img[:,:,3]/255.0) +  l_img[y_offset:y_offset+s_img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+s_img.shape[1], c] * (1.0 - s_img[:,:,3]/255.0)
```