# How to overlay on picture on another images in Python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have a picture like this and i want to remove the background by adding a layer on top the image just like how photoshop layout works.

Original Picture
[image]

Mask/Layer
[image]

Final desired output
[image]

I am trying to do this iwth opencv's addweighed function but i am not able to get the desired output

```
im_overlay = cv2.imread('%s/%s.png'%(_src,camera_name.split(".")[0]))
img = cv2.addWeighted(im, 1, im_overlay, 0.0, 0)
showImage(img)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image) or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv)

Comment: Already tried that, as mentioned in the problem the code did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the mask is strange for OpenCv to read on my system (using opencv 3.4.2). I was able to read it with cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED but it show me that your mask has 4 channels (I was expecting only one channel). The code below produce opposite or what you would expect:

```
 img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\...\Desktop\\W1kle.jpg")
 mask = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\...\Desktop\LZdyB.png",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) 
 mask = mask[:,:,3]
 res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
 cv2.imshow("image",res)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: You are right it is opposite to what i was looking for but to make it work on my case, i reversed the mask. Works smoothly. Thanks