# how to fix png image onto another image with opencv with transparent background

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to add glasses PNG image onto another image, but i get the PNG image with white background which hides the face.

I need to know what i did wrong please.

Original face image

[image: original face image]

Original glasses image

[image: original glasses image]

Expected result

[image: here what i get as result]

```
import cv2
import numpy
img = cv2.imread("barack-obama.jpg")
lunette = cv2.imread("lunette.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor = 1.1, minNeighbors = 5)   

r = 500.0 / img.shape[1]
dim = (500, int(img.shape[0] * r))
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

 grey = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grey, 1.3, 5)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:

roi_grey = grey[y:y+h, x:x+w]
roi_color = resized[y:y + h, x:x + w]
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_grey)
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

lunette = cv2.resize(lunette , (w,h))
w, h, c = lunette.shape 
for i in range(0, w):
for j in range(0, h):

    if lunette[i, j][0] != 0:
        resized[y + i, x + j] = lunette[i, j][1]
#help please
cv2.imshow('img',resized)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy:

- Read the background image (Obama)
- Read the overlay image (glasses) unchanged
- Extract the base BGR channels from the overlay image
- Extract the alpha channel from the overlay image as a mask
- Insert the BGR channels of the overlay into the background image at the desired location
- Insert the mask into a black image the size of the background image at the desired location
- Use Numpy where to composite the new background and overlay images using the new mask image
- Save the result

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read background image
img = cv2.imread("obama.jpg")
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# read overlay image
img2 = cv2.imread("sunglasses.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ht2, wd2 = img2.shape[:2]

# extract alpha channel as mask and base bgr images
bgr = img2[:,:,0:3]
mask = img2[:,:,3]

# insert bgr into img at desired location and insert mask into black image
x = 580
y = 390

bgr_new = img.copy()
bgr_new[y:y+ht2, x:x+wd2] = bgr

mask_new = np.zeros((ht,wd), dtype=np.uint8)
mask_new[y:y+ht2, x:x+wd2] = mask
mask_new = cv2.cvtColor(mask_new, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# overlay the base bgr image onto img using mask
result = np.where(mask_new==255, bgr_new, img)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('obama_glasses.jpg', result)

# display results
cv2.imshow('bgr', bgr)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('bgr_new', bgr_new)
cv2.imshow('mask_new', mask_new)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use cvzone library for solve this problem.

1. install cvzone library

   ```
   pip install cvzone
   ```
2. import cvzone in your project

   ```
   import cvzone
   ```
3. imread your emoji with following format

   ```
   lunette = cv2.imread("lunette.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
   ```
4. now replace the your emoji like this:

   ```
   YOUR BACKGROUND PICTURE = cvzone.overlayPNG(YOUR BACKGROUND PICTURE, lunette , [x, y])
   ```