# Put image on another image using python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, object-tracking

Hello i'm using python to track objects in a video and i want to show an image on  top of the object instead of a text.

The current line that im using to show text on top of the target box :

```
cv2.putText(img_current_frame ,"object name",(int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]-45)),0, 0.75, (0,0,0),2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already an answer for this: [overlay a smaller image on a larger image python OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv)

In your case, you could wrap this functionality with the following:

```py
def overlay_image(im1, im2, x_offset, y_offset):
    '''Mutates im1, placing im2 over it at a given offset.'''
    im1[y_offset:y_offset+im2.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset+im2.shape[1]] = im2
```

then call it:

```py
im_over = cv2.imread("my_overlay_image.png")
overlay_image(img_current_frame, im_over, 10, 10)
```

(as per the referenced solution)

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer to composite text with the PIL [`.text()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) method:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.open("blank.png").convert("RGBA")
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((10, 10), "Hello world!")
img.show()
```

Or if you have pixels, then use [alpha_composite()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.alpha_composite).

If you stick with cv2,
then [addWeighted()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) will help you blend in a logo image with alpha set to taste.
Or you can just use the matrix addition operator:

```
output = img_current_frame + logo
```