# When pasting an image on another image, how to keep the foreground image transparent?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to put an image on top of another using OpenCV / Pillow, while keeping the foreground image transparent. If you look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNDGd.jpg), you can see that everything is going smoothly, except I'm not sure how to keep the image transparent.

I've tried implementing [this StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv) by `@fireant` into my program, but nothing seems to work out.

**How can I execute `index.py` as normal, but keep the foreground png transparent?**

### Images

[dot_transparent.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5JbC.jpg)

[image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGD4g.jpg)

### index.py

```
import os
import numpy
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
import json

def upload_files():
    #https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/matt/Python/LazerEyes/haarcascade_eye.xml')

    #https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/matt/Python/LazerEyes/haarcascade_eye.xml')

    img = cv2.imread('new.png')
    img_to_place = cv2.imread('dot_transparent.png')

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_to_place = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    img_h, img_w = gray.shape
    img_to_place_h, img_to_place_w = gray_to_place.shape

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            resized_img = cv2.resize(img_to_place, (eh, ew), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            resized_img_h, resized_img_w, _ = resized_img.shape

            roi_color[ey:ey+resized_img_h, ex:ex+resized_img_w, :] = resized_img
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specific alpha values for each pixel, I'd follow another approach, and implement a pixel-wise [alpha blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), disregarding any alpha channel in the final image.

I borrowed some lines from [Quang Hoang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340226/11089932):

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Read images
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
dot = cv2.imread('dot_transparent.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Manual manipulating one eye
ex, ey, ew, eh = 1430, 1490, 400, 400
dot = cv2.resize(dot, (eh, ew))

# Prepare pixel-wise alpha blending
dot_alpha = dot[..., 3] / 255.0
dot_alpha = np.repeat(dot_alpha[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
dot = dot[..., :3]

# Pixel-wise alpha blending
img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew, :] = img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew, :] * (1 - dot_alpha) + dot * dot_alpha

# Output
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
plt.imshow(img[..., [2, 1, 0]])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Matplotlib:    3.3.4
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks great but I tried implementing your solution in my code but received `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (22,22,3) (1000,1000,3)` How can I implement your solution in `index.py`?

Comment: Obviously, you haven't resized the "dot" image, this has shape `(1000, 1000, 3)` to fit the found ROI, which seems to have shape `(22, 22, 3)`. Without seeing your updated code, it's impossible to help. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66339930/edit) your question, and put your updated code below your existing question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the `dot_transparent.png` with `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGE` flag, then you have the alpha channel (otherwise, you only have 3 channel)

```
img = cv2.imread('faces.jpg')
to_replace = cv2.imread('dot_transparent.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
# sample eye dectection
ex,ey,ew,eh = 1600, 1600,200,200

resized_replace = cv2.resize(to_replace, (eh,ew))

img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew] = np.where(resized_replace[...,-1:]<50, 
                                   img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew],
                                   resized_replace[...,:-1]
                            )

# show with imshow
plt.imshow(img[...,::-1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to keep all the transparency? Not just removing the black? IE. https://i.imgur.com/2Z01EJb.jpg

Comment: Try increasing the threshold, e.g. 50. See updated answer.