# Why can't I place my image on eye detection?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, opencv3.0

I want to place a transparent image on the location of where `cv2` detects my eyes. I've accomplished the main two steps, and now I need to combine them.

For instance, here is the output with the [image transparency working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Yt5.jpg), and here is the output with the [eye detection working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuD0w.png). The script and images are below, I'm not sure what to do.

### Images

[dot_transparent.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5JbC.jpg)

[image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGD4g.jpg)

### app.py

```py
import os
import numpy
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath

def upload_files():
    #https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/matt/Python/LazerEyes/haarcascade_eye.xml')

    #https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/matt/Python/LazerEyes/haarcascade_eye.xml')

    img = cv2.imread('new.png')
    dot = cv2.imread('dot_transparent.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_to_place = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    img_h, img_w = gray.shape
    img_to_place_h, img_to_place_w = gray_to_place.shape

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            dot = cv2.resize(dot, (eh, ew))
            # Prepare pixel-wise alpha blending
            dot_alpha = dot[..., :3] / 255.0
            dot_alpha = numpy.repeat(dot_alpha[..., numpy.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
            dot = dot[..., :3]

            resized_img = cv2.resize(dot, (eh, ew), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            resized_img_h, resized_img_w, _ = resized_img.shape

            #pointsOnFace = []
            #integersToAppend = eh
            #pointsOnFace.append(integersToAppend)
            #print(pointsOnFace)

            roi_color[ey:ey+resized_img_h, ex:ex+resized_img_w, :] = resized_img

    cv2.imwrite('out.png', img)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66339930/11089932 For each `(ex, ey, ew, eh)`, i.e. inside that loop, you need to get a copy of `dot`, resize it w.r.t. `ew, eh`, and execute the alpha blending step from my earlier answer. You simply left out that part in your current code!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When pasting an image on another image, how to keep the foreground image transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339930/when-pasting-an-image-on-another-image-how-to-keep-the-foreground-image-transpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340777/11089932) into the given code (and minimizing the resulting code), the solution might look like this:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('new.jpg')
dot = cv2.imread('dot_transparent.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray[y:y+h, x:x+w])

    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:

        # Filter out small detections, if you're only want to have the eyes
        if ew < 100 or eh < 100:
            continue

        d = cv2.resize(dot.copy(), (eh, ew))
        d_alpha = d[..., 3] / 255.0
        d_alpha = np.repeat(d_alpha[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
        d = d[..., :3]

        img[y+ey:y+ey+eh, x+ex:x+ex+ew, :] = \
            img[y+ey:y+ey+eh, x+ex:x+ex+ew, :] * (1 - d_alpha) + d * d_alpha

cv2.imwrite('out.png', img)
```

That's the output (I filtered out small detections, such that only the actual eyes are overlayed):

[image]

Finetuning the exact locations might still be needed, but I think that's an issue coming from the Haar cascade classifier itself.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```