# Is there a method to copy the amount of motion blur of one image to another in python, preferably using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, motion-detection, motion-blur

I'm adding an image in a video stream and would like to adjust the amount of motion blur so it matches the surroundings in the video stream. I would like to detect how much horizontal and vertical motion blur is present in a region of interest (ROI) of the frame of the video stream, and copy that to the image I'm inserting.

The goal is to make it look like the stream has not been edited.

I've performed a fast fourier transform (FFT) on the ROI with the expected result, but don't know how to copy that information onto my image that I'm inserting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv

Comment: @iGian I'm afraid this has nothing to do with motion blur, thanks though.