# Overlay smaller image to larger image in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I know this question has been asked for several times, e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv), but my problem is I need to overlay a smaller PNG image with a larger PNG image, where **both** images need to maintain their transparency in the output.

For example, smaller image is like:
[image]
... larger image is like:
[image]
(The image above has only 1 pixel filled with white color and 90% transparency)

Using the code examples given in the previous question ([overlay a smaller image on a larger image python OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063070/overlay-a-smaller-image-on-a-larger-image-python-opencv)), the larger background image will be in black.

```
def overlay_image_alpha(img, img_overlay, x, y, alpha_mask):
    """Overlay `img_overlay` onto `img` at (x, y) and blend using `alpha_mask`.

    `alpha_mask` must have same HxW as `img_overlay` and values in range [0, 1].
    """
    # Image ranges
    y1, y2 = max(0, y), min(img.shape[0], y + img_overlay.shape[0])
    x1, x2 = max(0, x), min(img.shape[1], x + img_overlay.shape[1])

    # Overlay ranges
    y1o, y2o = max(0, -y), min(img_overlay.shape[0], img.shape[0] - y)
    x1o, x2o = max(0, -x), min(img_overlay.shape[1], img.shape[1] - x)

    # Exit if nothing to do
    if y1 >= y2 or x1 >= x2 or y1o >= y2o or x1o >= x2o:
        return

    # Blend overlay within the determined ranges
    img_crop = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    img_overlay_crop = img_overlay[y1o:y2o, x1o:x2o]
    alpha = alpha_mask[y1o:y2o, x1o:x2o, np.newaxis]
    alpha_inv = 1.0 - alpha

    img_crop[:] = alpha * img_overlay_crop + alpha_inv * img_crop


# Prepare inputs
x, y = 50, 0
img = np.array(Image.open("template.png"))
img_overlay_rgba = np.array(Image.open("../foo.png"))

# Perform blending
alpha_mask = img_overlay_rgba[:, :, 3] / 255.0
img_result = img[:, :, :3].copy()
img_overlay = img_overlay_rgba[:, :, :3]
overlay_image_alpha(img_result, img_overlay, x, y, alpha_mask)

# Save result
Image.fromarray(img_result).save("img_result.png")
```

Result:
[image]

My desired result is to maintain the larger image's transparency.

May I know how to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using openCV to overlay transparent image onto another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895785/using-opencv-to-overlay-transparent-image-onto-another-image)

Comment: and here's a recipe for composing the alpha channels as well: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried the first link before I asked this question and it did not work. I haven't tried the second though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the correct output. Fully transparent images (like your template image) have the pixel value of 0 on empty areas which represents black. If you were to use semi-transparent templates (which have pixels value greater than 0 even if they are slightly transparent). You should see this:

[image]

**Answer 2:**

Your output images are 24bit. (Which means you get rid of thhe alpha channel before saving it). I looked into your code and saw the lines 34 and 35;

```
img_result = img[:, :, :3].copy()   
img_overlay = img_overlay_rgba[:, :, :3]
```

You're sending RGB images to `overlay_image_alpha` function. Change this to;

```
img_result = img.copy()
img_overlay = img_overlay_rgba
```

To preserve Alpha channel information.

New Output:

[image]

On Photoshop:

[image]

Comment: I checked the output image (that black one) in photoshop, and it seems not a transparent image. (Actually the larger image is fully transparent and it appears to be "white" in Stack Overflow website)

Comment: @TaihouKai I edited the answer, can you check the new method please?